# Windows 7 upgrade on XP and Vista

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, windows-vista

I am upgrading a Windows XP (32-bit) machine and a Windows Vista (32-bit) machine to Windows 7 (32-bit).  The most important files and accounts are on the Windows XP machine.

What I would like to do is the following:

1. backup the XP machine using Windows Easy Transfer
2. upgrade the Windows Vista machine to a fresh install of Windows 7
3. install the XP backup on the Vista machine and see if everything is working

Is this possible?  I would have thought its possible as once the Vista machine is upgraded to Windows 7 it should be the same as if I had upgraded the XP machine, but I don't want to waste my time if its not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I've found the answer on the [microsoft technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd446674(WS.10).aspx):

> Additionally, if you are installing Windows 7 on a new computer, you can transfer settings and files from any other computer running Windows Vista or Windows XP by using Windows Easy Transfer.

Effectively I will be wiping (i.e. not upgrading) the Vista machine so it will be the same as a new computer and I can then restore files from a XP Easy Transfer

Comment: Well I did this an it worked, so this was the answer